# How to calculate the probability at a given condition when I know the outcome in pymc3?

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc3

```
import arviz as az
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from pymc3.math import dot, exp
import pandas as pd

        trace = pm.sample(
            10000,
            chains=4,
            tune=400,
            return_inferencedata=True,
        )

    summary = az.summary(trace, hdi_prob=0.95)
    print(summary)

with m:
   pm.set_data({"condition1": [val1], "condition2": [val2], "condition3": 
   [val3]})
   ppc = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace)
```

In the above code I have the values of three condition available and I know the output as well, I want to calculate the probability of arriving at that output.